# What is equivalent of doOnSuccess method from Mono in Flux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In my previous version of API, I have used **Mono** as a return type. When everything works fine, I logged in **doOnSuccess** method.

After the API method return type was changed to **Flux**, I cannot use the **doOnSuccess** for logging.

What is equivalent for **doOnSuccess** method for Flux, please?

Comment: A flux emits 0 to N times. A Mono emits 0 or 1 time. When do you want the log to happen?

Comment: After what all the items were processed in the previous map method.

Comment: So, when the Flux completes. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnComplete-java.lang.Runnable-

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is equivalent for doOnSuccess method for Flux

`doOnComplete()` is probably the closest match, which will add a side effect when the `Flux` completes successfully (without an error.)

As an addendum, `doOnTerminate()` is the equivalent operator which will add a side effect whenever the `Flux` terminates, either normally, or by throwing an exception.